# Remover extensão .php das páginas , porém aparece ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: htaccess, apache, http-status-404

Estou querendo retirar a extensão .php das minhas páginas da web.

Criei um arquivo .htaccess conforme abaixo e coloquei no diretório raiz

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Quando tento acessar a página tirando a extensão,está dando página não encontrada. conforme abaixo:

```
ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o .htaccess para

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

na imagem abaixo veja que acessei o http://localhost/teste/info  (que corresponde ao info.php)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

```js
Faça desta forma:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta. Mas não funcionou .